# Multidimensional scaling in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, scaling, multidimensional-array

Is there any library for C# to do multidimensional scaling, like the mdscaling function in Matlab?
I'm trying to visualy represent multidimensional data on a single graph

Answer (score 1):

Well, by googling Principal Component Analysis (its the same thing) i find some libraries, ended up using some portuguese one.